# AndroidAnnotations not compatible with DataBinding since Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-annotations, android-gradle-3.0

**UPDATE**

It turned out that the issue is not with AndroidAnnotations. There is a bug in the gradle plugin 3.0 that does not find generated classes when compiling DataBinding views. There is an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68892352) on the Android issuetracker.

**ORIGINAL POST**

After updating my code to Android Studio 3.0 (gradle plugin 3.0.0) I am getting compile errors on all custom views annotated with `@EView` from AndroidAnnotations.

An example of an error:

```
Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:data' with parameter type com.example.databinding_aa.databindingaa.BindingData on com.example.databinding_aa.databindingaa.BindingViewAA_.`
```

All errors are related to setters using the DataBinding `@BindingAdapter` annotation.

- It worked fine under Android Studio 2.3.3
- I've created a GitHub issue: [Link to GitHub issue](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/issues/2074)
- I've created an example project to reproduce the error: [Link to example project (GitHub)](https://github.com/couchcrew-thomas/DatabindingAA3)

Here is an example of an annotated custom view and how it is integrated into a layout:

```
@EView
public class BindingViewAA extends AppCompatTextView {

    @BindingAdapter("data")
    public static void setData(BindingViewAA view, BindingData data) {
        view.setText(data.getBar() + data.getFoo());
    }

    public BindingViewAA(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public BindingViewAA(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public BindingViewAA(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

The layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    <data>

        <variable
            name="greeting"
            type="String"/>

        <variable
            name="data"
            type="com.example.databinding_aa.databindingaa.BindingData"/>

    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.example.databinding_aa.databindingaa.BindingViewAA_
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:data="@{data}"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

And the data POJO:

```
public class BindingData {

    private final String foo;
    private final String bar;

    public BindingData(String foo, String bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }
}
```

Has anyone had success using AndroidAnnotations and DataBinding with Android Studio 3.0, yet?

Comment: @McFarlene : were you able to figure this out? I am kind of same problems here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47988601/android-studio-3-0-databinding-issues

Comment: There is no solution, yet. I've updated the post. The problem does not lie withing AndroidAnnotations

Comment: I too have created a bug - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71516833